# Update image using java & SQL

Tags: java, swing

The update of the image works fine, but when I do a partial update to a record, for example I update "Name, City, Zipecode" without updating the image. I got the success saved message, but when a search for the updated record I found the image is gone "null" ?

```
    private void UpdateEmplyee() throws Exception {
        try {

            int EMP_ID = Integer.parseInt(this.empidtxt.getText());

            String FNAME = this.firstnametxt.getText().toUpperCase();
            String LNAME = this.lastnametxt.getText().toUpperCase();
            String ADDRESS = this.addresstxt.getText().toUpperCase();
            String CITY = this.citytxt.getText().toUpperCase();
            String STATE = this.statetxt.getText().toUpperCase();
            int ZCODE = Integer.parseInt(this.zipcodetxt.getText());
            String PHONE_N = this.phonetxt.getText();

            //I need something here to keep the image as it is, if not updated??
            //Icon image = this.AttImglbl.getIcon();


            EmployeeRecord emp = new EmployeeRecord();

            emp.setFNAME(FNAME);
            emp.setLNAME(LNAME);
            emp.setADDRESS(ADDRESS);
            emp.setADDRESS(ADDRESS);
            emp.setCITY(CITY);
            emp.setSTATE(STATE);
            emp.setZCODE(ZCODE);
            emp.setPHONE_N(PHONE_N);
            emp.setEMP_IMG(EMP_IMG);//byte[]

            EmployeeRecordDao empdao = new EmployeeRecordDao();

            int result = empdao.UpdateEmployee(emp, EMP_ID);

            if (result != 0) {
                dm.Message("Your data has been saved!");
            } else {
                dm.Message("Your data has been rejected!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            dm.Message("An error has occurred. Please try again");
        }

        empidtxt.requestFocus();

    }

private void AttachImage() {
        try {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showOpenDialog(attachmentbtn.getParent());
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
            Image img;
            img = getToolkit().createImage(filename);
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(200, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
            AttImglbl.setIcon(ii);

            File image = new File(filename);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
            }

            EMP_IMG = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (HeadlessException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: So, the problem is when you do "partial updates". But the posted code doesn't do any partial update.

Comment: This seems to have everything to do with images and DBs, but nothing to do with Swing!  Can you successfully 'update the image' from a console app.?  If so, it 'might have' something to do with Swing.  If not, then it doesn't.  If you haven't tried that yet, you should.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: If I updated everything include the image, there is no problem. But if I updated everything except the image. then the problem is the image get replaced with "null" and doesnt show up anymore ??

Comment: I fixed it, thank you